# How can I switch from server kernel to desktop kernel?

Tags: server, kernel

I want to change the kernel-type from server to desktop. I installed my system from a server CD, but then installed gnome and now I want to change from server kernel to desktop kernel. How can I do this securely?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
sudo reboot
```

And after reboot, check your kernel version with:

```
uname -a
```

Comment: one remark to @David, just check at boot time which kernel is selected by default, and it should be your new kernel