# Can I Use Ubuntu Server As A Desktop?

Tags: graphics, skype, webcam

an older relative of mine still has Windows XP. The hardware is ok for XP, but definetively too weak for Windows 7. Also, I think, Ubuntu would be a nice OS for him to work with, since it's easy and has a great feel.

**HARDWARE**
The machine has 1 processor with one core (3 GHz) [*Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz*], 1,5 GB RAM, 80 GB HDD. But it has some weird VGA-Chip [*VIA/S3G UniChrome Pro IGP*]

**PROBLEM**
I installed Ubuntu 12.04, Lubuntu 13.04, Xubuntu 13.10 and even Linux Mint: I simply cannot get a desktop. All the installations run without problems, but I keep getting stuck with **The system is running in low-graphics mode**. I tried [all the answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) to this problem (since there is a good thread concerning this error here), but I think, the VGA-Chip simply doesn't do it (someone wrote "Unity requires: Any graphics card with OpenGL 1.4 support"). I spent two days, trying to get to a desktop, I couldn't succeed.

**SOLUTION?**
Out of curiosity, I installed Ubuntu 8, which worked fine. Of course, I couldn't update it. Then, by accident, I installed Ubuntu Server 10 (instead of Ubuntu Desktop 10). After the installation, I installed a desktop (sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop). Then, I updated to **Ubuntu Server 12.04, still with desktop**. Everything works fine. I have an Ubuntu LTS with a working desktop.

**QUESTION**
**Is there any serious reason, why I shouldn't run a Ubuntu Server as a Desktop?**

The guy, I'm doing this for, just wants:
 - *open office* or *libre office*
 - internet browser (*firefox* would be good)
 - *thunderbird*
 - *skype* (yeah, it's Microsoft... but some of his relatives are outside the country and using skype)
 - software for *viewing* and collecting *photos*
 - to use a *HP laserprinter*, a *standard-webcam* (for skype) and *card-reader*
Everything shouldn't be a problem, as far as I see it.

If there IS a problem with running a Server OS as a Desktop: Is there any other way to install Ubuntu Desktop and tell the OS not to use any kind of desktop-features, that need newer VGA-cards (kind of like the windows 2000 theme)?

Yeah, I could make him buy a new pc, but I just hate to waste. This guy doesn't want to play the newest games, cut videos or render 3D-graphics. He just needs some office-programs and internet-access.

What do you think?

Regards,

Comment: No running a server as desktop is fine, the only slight problem you might have is that the kernels are optimized for servers, so running on battery similar isn't what they are meant to do. It will work fine in terms of stability but it would be more efficient if it had the desktop kernels.

Comment: Try something lighter, maybe even TCL should work(of course install libreoffice and firefox). There are many lightweight distros in the wild.

Comment: Consider using Lubuntu or CrunchBang #!

Comment: I did install Lubuntu. Didn't work.

Comment: @Alvar add your comment as an answer to the question. It seems to be the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu server can be turned into an Ubuntu desktop by removing server related packages and installing `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

Check these questions for a How-to on the topic

- [Switching from Server to Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322122/switching-from-server-to-desktop)
- [How can I switch from server kernel to desktop kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68319/how-can-i-switch-from-server-kernel-to-desktop-kernel?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Since Lubuntu, Xubuntu and others didn't work, I sticked to Ubuntu Server with a graphical user interface. No problems so far. Seems to be an option, if you've got an older PC with a graphic-card, that just won't do.

Cheers.