# How to run GUI desktop from root

Tags: root, gui

I upgraded to 18.04 and now when my system boots it only goes into root.  How can I run or boot directly into GUI desktop mode?

Comment: *it only goes into root*: Did you mean in command line mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want a choice about starting a Desktop system or a Server system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059887/i-want-a-choice-about-starting-a-desktop-system-or-a-server-system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start ubuntu-desktop after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04)